# How to delete a segment of a string with a specific start and end in R using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, r, replace, wildcard

I have a string.

```
str = c("F14 : M114L","W15 : M116L, W15 : M118L","W15 : D111L, F14 : E112L, F14 : M116L")
```

The goal is to delete anything between : and L (also includes the white space right in front of :) such that I would end up having

```
"F14", "W15, W15", "W15, F14, F14"
```

I am thinking using

```
gsub(" : [[:alnum:]]L", "", str)
```

But clearly it does not work. Don't know if there is something like a wildcard that can represent any number of digits and characters between : and L.

Comment: I think a `+` will do it: `gsub(" : [[:alnum:]]+L","",str)`

Comment: It works. Haven't used regular expressions in a while. I forgot [[:alnum:]] only accounts for one letter or number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do it:

```
gsub(" : .*?L", "", str)
#[1] "F14"           "W15, W15"      "W15, F14, F14"
```

Comment: Is the `?` telling `.*` to stop when it hits an `L`, making it nongreedy or something? I've only seen `?` as a quantifier before

Comment: @Frank Exactly, the `?` after a quantifier makes it non-greedy.  It becomes a "lazy" quantifier.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with ease using the **qdapRegex** package that I maintain:

```
str = c("F14 : M114L","W15 : M116L, W15 : M118L","W15 : D111L, F14 : E112L, F14 : M116L")

library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(str, "\\s:", "L")
## [1] "F14"           "W15, W15"      "W15, F14, F14"
```

**qdapRegex** aims to be useful as it teaches.  If you are interested in the regex used...

```
S("@rm_between", "\\s:", "L")
## [1] "(\\s:)(.*?)(L)"

gsub(S("@rm_between", "\\s:", "L") , "", str)
```

Answer (score 6):

Couple of approaches.

Take the first few letters if it's always three:

```
substr(str,1,3)
```

I personally like `stringr` too. It makes extraction really straightforward. Pattern what you want, not what you don't want.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str,"[A-Z][0-9]*")
```

I've simplified these for a vector, but you have sub elements, you'll need something like:

```
splits <- strsplit(str,", ")
result <- lapply(splits, substr, start = 1, stop = 3 )
```

or

```
result <- lapply(splits, str_extract, pattern = "[A-Z][0-9]*")
```

Comment: Ah yes, for the substr solution. Good catch.